# SQL Query and RAM issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ram

I have an sql query which I am trying to run on a server which has 8GB RAM.  If I restart the server, it starts up and the memory usage is about 1.2GB.

If I then execute the query, by the time the query has finished, the RAM usage goes to about 4GB and seems to stay there, even over night.

If I then execute the query again (the next day), the RAM usage goes up to about 7GB and stays there even when the query has finished.

If I then try to execute the query again after waiting 24 hours, the RAM usage is still at 7GB, but this time, the query starts returning out of memory errors.

My question is, how to I clear the memory usage when the query has finished running?  Ideally, it would be good if the sql script itself could clear the RAM usage when it finished it's main job.

---

The server version is:

It's Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64).

---

The error message is:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is insufficient memory available in the buffer pool.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Project1.Form1.intenseProcess3() in c:\Users\oshirowanen\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Form1.cs:line 117
ClientConnectionId:33f515db-0086-4f88-a8fd-e7779d92d030
Error Number:802,State:20,Class:17 SqlException caught.
```

Comment: Can you add detailed error messages?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server instance, select Properties, click the "Memory" page, and ensure the "Maximum server memory" is set to something reasonable, in your case, 4096.  By default, SQL Server will use up all available memory and hold onto it.  This is the first step.

Comment: I hope that's just your personal test server or something like that. Otherwise I would definitely recommend you to purchase more RAM.

Comment: @pmbAustin, thanks, I've done that and have started the script, lets see what happens...

Comment: @JamesZ, even if I get 1TB of RAM, if the RAM isn't cleared down after each execution of the query, that will mean I will start getting memory errors if the query runs 250 times or more.

Comment: @oshirowanen The memory is not supposed to clear because it's used for caching data. query plans etc. You're basically supposed to give SQL Server a lot of memory so it can perform as fast as possible -- but you need to specify the maximum limit, always.

Comment: Is this straight SQL or is the CLR based magic in the query?

Comment: I would not consider buying more RAM for a query executed only once every 24 hours.

Comment: @dsolimano, not 100% sure what you mean.  I have a stored procedure, which is executed by a .NET program.  The stored procedure returns it's results to the program.

Comment: @Alexander, running it once in 24 hours was just a test.  based on that test, if I run the query in full mode, I get the feeling it will take about a month to finish...

Comment: @pmbAustin, SQL Server Managedment Studio was set to 2PB for some reason.  I've now got it set to 4GB, and will let it execute over night.  Will let you know what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your max server memory to leave at least a gig or two available to the OS and any other software on your server.  SQL will cache data and only release it when approaching it's limits.

> Use max server memory to prevent the SQL Server buffer pool from using
>   more than the specified amount of memory, thus leaving remaining
>   memory available to start other applications quickly. SQL Server does
>   not immediately allocate the memory specified in max server memory on
>   startup. Memory usage is increased as needed by SQL Server until
>   reaching the value specified in max server memory. SQL Server cannot
>   exceed this memory usage unless the value of max server memory is
>   raised.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

You can change it with Management Studio by right clicking on the server in the object viewer and selecting properties.  Then change the Maximum Server Memory value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To free memory, you can use but this commands but they are only usefull for example to test query duration in a constant contex. SQL Server is clever enough to through away object from RAM when it is needed.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Are you sure you don't use `DBCC PINTABLE` because this command force SQL to keep object in RAM ?

Comment: Wasn't DBCC PINTABLE removed already in 2000 or something like that? Anyhow, it should not be used even if it still exists :)